# How to check if form view is filterbyform

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am using two forms. The form this code is from shows a weekly summary of booked appointments: it contains text boxes that display a count of appointments for each team on each day, and daily and weekly totals. I have replaced the double click events for all the text boxes with a function. When a text box is double clicked another form is used to display records that are counted in that text box. It all works great unless the user already has the details form open and has selected the filter by form option but has not yet applied the filter.

I check to see if the details form is open, if not then I open it with an SQL sting to show the records for the counted appointments. If the details form is already open then I check to see if a filter is applied, remove it, then filter to show the records for the counted appointments.

```
If CurrentProject.AllForms("MyForm").IsLoaded = False Then 
  DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", , mysql
Else
  If Forms("MyForm").FilterOn = True Then Forms("MyForm").FilterOn = False
  Forms("MyForm").Filter = myfil
  Forms("MyForm").FilterOn = True
End If
```

How can I check if the details form is in the filter by form view/state? and if it is, close it. So I can apply the filter to show the records of the counted appointments.

Comment: I simply close the already-opened form in these cases, and then re-open it with my filter. <shrug> -- To avoid flicker, you can do `Application.Echo False` while doing this.

Comment: I have consider this approach but my users resize the forms and arrange them to their liking, so I would have to record the position and size of the form to then reopen it in the same location and size. I also considered catching the error to trigger the close and reopen. I was hoping that there would be a form property I could check, but I have had no luck finding it.

Comment: I found this which give me more information but no solution to the problem, i does how ever make the question more specific https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191892.aspx. How do I test for these filer augments  acFilterByForm, acFilterAdvanced?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, good find with the `Filter` event!

I would use a public variable in the module of `MyForm` that saves the FilterByForm state and can be accessed from the outside:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public bFilterByForm As Boolean
```

It is set and cleared in the `Filter` and `ApplyFilter` events:

```
Private Sub Form_ApplyFilter(Cancel As Integer, ApplyType As Integer)

    ' acShowAllRecords = 0
    ' acApplyFilter = 1
    ' acCloseFilterWindow = 2
    Debug.Print "Form_ApplyFilter: " & ApplyType

    ' I don't think checking for ApplyType is necessary - 
    ' in each case the filter windows is closed.

    ' FilterByForm is finished!
    bFilterByForm = False

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Filter(Cancel As Integer, FilterType As Integer)

    ' acFilterByForm = 0
    ' acFilterAdvanced = 1
    Debug.Print "Form_Filter: " & FilterType

    If FilterType = acFilterByForm Then
        ' FilterByForm is active!
        bFilterByForm = True
    End If

End Sub
```

and using this variable your calling sub can check the FilterByForm state:

```
If Form_MyForm.bFilterByForm Then
    ' FilterByForm is active: close the form!
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "MyForm"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", , mysql
End If
```

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to cancel the filterbyform rather then close and reopen the form.

Answer (score 0):

Massive thank you to Andre for all his help, my final solution is mostly his work with a slight edit to allow the form to stay open. I added this function to details form AKA MyForm

```
Public Sub RunApplyFilter()
Forms("MyForm").SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdApplyFilterSort
End Sub
```

And the final checks use Andre method to identify if MyForm is in FilterByForm view.

```
If CurrentProject.AllForms("MyForm").IsLoaded = False Then
  DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", , mysql
Else 
  If [Form_MyForm].bFilterByForm = True Then Forms("MyForm").RunApplyFilter
  If Forms("MyForm").FilterOn = True Then Forms("MyForm").FilterOn = False
  Forms("MyForm").Filter = myfil
  Forms("MyForm").FilterOn = True
End If
```

Thanks again to Andre.

Comment: I replaced the acCmdApplyFilterSort with acCmdCloseWindow and it closes the filter window without applying a filter which I prefer greatly but once the window closes I get a "no record" error. any ideas?